# OpenCV Document Scanner - better quadrilateral detection

Tags: python, android, opencv, image-processing

I'm having troubles detecting the edges of the documents real-time from the camera as the backgrounds could vary and the color of the document could be very close to the background color.
Any help regardless of the programming language will be appreciated.

I've tried to do so by:

```
const val CLOSE_KERNEL_SIZE = 5.0
const val BLURRING_KERNEL_SIZE = 5.0
const val DILATE_KERNEL_SIZE = 5.0


val (threshold1, threshold2) = getCannyThresholds(src)

Imgproc.cvtColor(src, src, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

Imgproc.GaussianBlur(src, src, Size(BLURRING_KERNEL_SIZE, BLURRING_KERNEL_SIZE), 3.0)

Imgproc.Canny(src, destination, threshold1, threshold2)

val dilateKernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(DILATE_KERNEL_SIZE, DILATE_KERNEL_SIZE))
Imgproc.dilate(destination, destination, dilateKernel)

val kernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(
    Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE,
    Size(CLOSE_KERNEL_SIZE, CLOSE_KERNEL_SIZE)
)
Imgproc.morphologyEx(
    destination,
    destination,
    Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE,
    kernel,
    Point(-1.0, -1.0),
    10
)

val preview2 = Mat(destination, Rect(0, 0, destination.width(), destination.height()))
showPreview(preview2)
```

As canny thresholds are dynamically calculated based on this method:

```
val brightness = Core.mean(mat).`val`[0] / 255

val threshold1 = 10 / brightness
val threshold2 = 40 / brightness
```

And the contours are found by:

```
    private fun findLargestContours(inputMat: Mat): List<MatOfPoint>? {
        val mHierarchy = Mat()
        val mContourList: List<MatOfPoint> = ArrayList()
        //finding contours - as we are sorting by area anyway, we can use RETR_LIST - faster than RETR_EXTERNAL.
        Imgproc.findContours(inputMat, mContourList, mHierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        // Convert the contours to their Convex Hulls i.e. removes minor nuances in the contour
        val mHullList: MutableList<MatOfPoint> = ArrayList()
        val tempHullIndices = MatOfInt()
        for (i in mContourList.indices) {
            Imgproc.convexHull(mContourList[i], tempHullIndices)
            mHullList.add(hull2Points(tempHullIndices, mContourList[i]))
        }
        // Release mContourList as its job is done
        for (c in mContourList) {
            c.release()
        }
        tempHullIndices.release()
        mHierarchy.release()
        if (mHullList.size != 0) {
            mHullList.sortWith { lhs, rhs ->
                Imgproc.contourArea(rhs).compareTo(Imgproc.contourArea(lhs))
            }
            return mHullList.subList(0, min(mHullList.size, FIRST_MAX_CONTOURS))
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun hull2Points(hull: MatOfInt, contour: MatOfPoint): MatOfPoint {
        val indexes = hull.toList()
        val points: MutableList<Point> = ArrayList()
        val ctrList = contour.toList()
        for (index in indexes) {
            points.add(ctrList[index])
        }
        val point = MatOfPoint()
        point.fromList(points)
        return point
    }
```

As a result I am getting the following but the canny edge detection didn't workout as expected as the edges are not fully detected.  The contours found are drawn in green:
[image: Result]

Camera input:
[image: Camera input]

Note: I've tried with Hough Lines but as I am unable to remove the text there are too many lines.

Comment: there is no contrast separating the sheet from the table. both are white.

Comment: Photograph your documents on a dark table, not a white one!

Comment: Or use an AI background remover such as http://remove.bg